# Notifications getting disappered after clicking one notification in android

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-intentservice

IntentReceiver.java

```
 @Override
    protected void onPushReceived(Context context, PushMessage message, int notificationId) {

 Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationPayloadActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationPayloadActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appnotification)
                .setContentTitle("Warning")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .build();

     //   builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appnotification).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
}
```

When I receive multiple notifications, if I click on one notification it is taking me to the given activity but if I click back button on the activity all remaining notifications in the notification bar are getting disappeared.

Not sure what's causing that issue, please feel free to ask if the above is not clear

Comment: Is the notificationId unique for each notification?

Comment: I just did debugging and noticed notification id is coming different.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all your notifications have the same `notificationId`. Assert they have unique ones.